# ValueError: Found unknown categories ['IR', 'HN', 'MT', 'PH', 'NZ', 'CZ', 'MD'] in column 3 during transform

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to use Linear Regression, to predict salary in **USD**. I have the following data:

[image]

**Data:**

- **607** records
- **Numerical columns:** *year*, *salary*, *salary in USD*
- **Categorical columns:** *experience*, *type*, *residence*, *currency*, *remote work*, *company location*, and *company size*.
- **Target:** *salary in USD*

**Preprocessing dataset:**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

# Columns to drop:
drop_cols = ['Currency', 'Company location', 'Salary', 'Title']

# Attributes of interest
num_attributes = ['Year']
one_hot_attributes = ['Experience', 'Type', 'Remote work', 'Residence', 'Company size']

# Drop columns:
data.drop(drop_cols, 1, inplace=True)

# Setup transformer for column:
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer([
    ('nums', StandardScaler(), num_attributes),
    ('one_hot', OneHotEncoder(drop='first', sparse=False), one_hot_attributes)], 
                                remainder='passthrough')
```

**Pipe:**

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipe = Pipeline(steps =[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('model', LinearRegression()),
])

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**Perform prediction:**

```
prediction = pipe.predict(X_test)
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: Found unknown categories ['IR', 'HN', 'MT', 'PH', 'NZ', 'CZ', 'MD'] in column 3 during transform
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test data contains locations that were never seen during training, but you are using OneHotEncoder. How do you want to represent these never seen before locations?

You need to set `handle_unknown` parameter in `OneHotEncoder` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html. By default this is set to `error`. Instead you can choose for example you can set it to `ignore` (will encode it as 0s) or `infrequent_if_exist` which will create a dummy category (then you need to set `min_frequency` so that rare values from training data are mapped there)

E.g.

```
# Setup transformer for column:
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer([
    ('nums', StandardScaler(), num_attributes),
    ('one_hot', OneHotEncoder(drop='first',
                              sparse=False,
                              handle_unknown='ignore'), one_hot_attributes)], 
    remainder='passthrough')
```